# Show that a binomial Distribution is approximately normal distributed for $\sigma > 5$.

Tags: normal-distribution, binomial-distribution, standard-deviation

I'm supposed to show that a binomial Distribution is approximately normal distributed for $\sigma > 5$, where $\sigma$ is the Standard Deviation.

I'm not sure how to even understand the Question, since a binomial Distribution is a discrete Distribution, while a normal Distribution is a continuous one, as far as I know.

Comment: If you haven't already, might want to check : Normal approximation section in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Comment: The figure in the Wikipedia article shows how the two are related.  You basically spread the discrete value of the binomial over the range $\pm 0.5$ to make a continuous distribution, then ignore or smooth out the stairsteps.  Note the criterion in the article is $np$ and $n(1-p)$ are both greater than $5$ (or $9$ depending on how good a fit you want) while your question has $np(1-p) \gt 5$, which is a little stricter.

Comment: The way I have done this in the long ago past was to plug Stirling's approximation into the binomial distribution formula